# Are P2SH transactions with disabled opcodes relayed/mined?

Tags: script, bitcoin-core-development, p2sh, taproot, opcodes

Many OPCODES like OP_AND, OP_CAT, OP_SUBSTR are disabled as described in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script. Although, with Bitcoin Core 0.10.0 Gavin Andresen [proposed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4365) "any Script" in P2SH transactions to be relayed/mined:
[image]
I'm still unsure if this applies disabled opcodes. I've come across a Mainnet coinbase transaction with disabled "OP_AND" opcode [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/bcd93f13f78bc66e4ab5c3e468c386466d0aa307b15b58d0e42b8afa4fffaaba), and a Testnet transaction [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc-testnet/tx/19f8799e074bf253ac1ed39aa25d97b7fd5d82d962d268723971dd84a7cd08f3). I'm very curios if P2SH transactions with disabled opcodes in the redeem script relayed and mined on the BTC Mainnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that wiki [link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) you posted it states:

> If any opcode marked as disabled is present in a script, it must abort and fail.

An attempted UTXO spend with a failed script will not be relayed between nodes running Bitcoin Core (and other major implementations) and certainly won't be included in a mined block.

The mainnet coinbase [transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/bcd93f13f78bc66e4ab5c3e468c386466d0aa307b15b58d0e42b8afa4fffaaba) you link to includes an OP_AND in an input scriptSig. But input(s) in a coinbase transaction are ignored as it is mining new Bitcoins and is not spending from any output from another transaction.

The testnet [transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc-testnet/tx/19f8799e074bf253ac1ed39aa25d97b7fd5d82d962d268723971dd84a7cd08f3) you link to includes an OP_AND in an output scriptPubKey. It hasn't been spent and can't be spent because there is no scriptSig that can spend from it.

BIP-Tapscript ([BIP 342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki#specification)) proposes to make disabled opcodes like OP_AND OP_SUCCESSx which would mean that the Tapscript would automatically succeed if the opcode is encountered. This is so that new opcode functionality could potentially be introduced in a future soft fork without breaking backwards compatibility. But Taproot/Tapscript is not yet activated on the network at the time of writing (October 2020).